# Adding row colors based on unique rows in xlxswriter python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I was generating xlxs file from python python xlxswriter package. I want to generate rows with color coded based on the combination unique id. Please find the below output

[image]

**Current Logic:**

```py
fontcolor_indexlist = [data[0] for data in df_Index.select("index").filter(col("Invoice Calculation Date") == f'{InvoiceDate}').collect()]  #Getting index from pyspark dataframe

pandas_df = df_InvoiceDetails.drop("cellformat").toPandas()
 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"/tmp/{DetailsFileName}", engine="xlsxwriter")

cell_format = workbook.add_format({'valign': 'vcenter', 'align': 'center','fg_color': '#D3D3D3'})

if row_num in fontcolor_indexlist:
   worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, value, cell_format)
```

I tried the above code and wants to achieve the xlxs file with low code, similar to conditional formatting

Comment: Just want to clarify the logic. if current row id is the same as the previous row id, the current row should have the same colour as previous row. but if current row id is different from the previous row id, the current row should have a different colour?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to *alternate* the color of each `"id"`/block, I would use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)/[`write_row`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_row) :

```
# for convenience, i'm using df instead of pandas_df

D_FMT = {"valign": "vcenter", "align": "center"}
C_FMT = {"fg_color": "#D3D3D3"}
H_FMT = {"bold": 1}

SR, SC = 0, 0 # start row/col

with pd.ExcelWriter(f"/tmp/{DetailsFileName}", engine="xlsxwriter") as wr:
    wb = wr.book; ws = wb.add_worksheet("Sheet1")
    
    ws.write_row(SR, SC, df.columns, wb.add_format(H_FMT))

    for n, (_, g)in enumerate(df.groupby("id", sort=False)):
        for idx, row in zip(g.index, g.to_numpy()):
            _fmt = D_FMT if not n%2 else {**D_FMT, **C_FMT}
            ws.write_row(idx+1, SC, row, wb.add_format(_fmt))
```

[image]

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8],
        "No of times": [1, 2, 23, 12, 0, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2, 48, 10],
    }
)
```